# ReactJS app published to Github pages with custom domain

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I have a reactjs application that I created using the create-react-app. I have installed gh-pages and successfully deployed it to github pages (project page) using the following command:

gh-pages -d build

However, when I add a custom domain to my github project repository my application could not load the js and css files. My browser is looking for the following files:

```
http://my.custom.domain/<repo name>/static/css/main.caaf9ea4.css
http://my.custom.domain/<repo name>/static/js/main.76fabd7f.js
```

The correct link to load these files should be:

```
http://my.custom.domain/static/css/main.caaf9ea4.css
http://my.custom.domain/static/js/main.76fabd7f.js
```

In the GitHub repo pages, I have set custom domain to be 'my.custom.domain' (root domain without www). The source is gh-pages branch.

My DNS settings are:

- A record, @, value: 192.30.252.153
- A record, @, value: 192.30.252.154
- CNAME record, www, value: username.github.io

Any ideas how to change the settings so that repo name is not added to the domain?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your package.json have the attribute homepage. e.g.

```
  "homepage": "https://<git-USER>.github.io/",
```

That's literally what I just did with my cra projet. If you want to take a look on my project just look at the [develop branch](https://github.com/Kerry-G/kerrygd). However, I haven't use gh-pages -d build. I just built the project myself and create the branch gh-pages and put the content of my build into it. It should be the same though.

Comment: My GitHub page is for a project repo, so I have put the following attribute into package.json


    "homepage": "https://<gith-user>.github.io/<repo_name>",

Comment: And this is why your browser is looking for 
http://my.custom.domain/<repo name>/static/css/main.caaf9ea4.css

Comment: after changing the homepage attribute to point to my username.github.io, the site becomes not found.

I believe the "homepage" attribute should be "https://git-user.githbu.io/reponame", according to [create-react-app doc](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#github-pages)

Comment: I know, but when I switched to a custom domain I had to change my homepage setting. 

Anyway, have you done the step 5 of your guide? Added the CNAME file to your project. If you look into my github project I linked on my last comment, it is a create-react-app project hosted by gh-pages with a costum domain

Comment: I have finally solved this. Since I am using custom domain, I have set the homepage attribute to be 

    `https://my.custom.domain/`

. I have also inadvertently deleted the CNAME file. After adding back the CNAME file, the site comes back to life. Thanks @kerrygougeon for your help.

Comment: @silverw You mean only by changing the homepage attribute, you were able to fix the issue ? Actually for me after doing this site becomes not found :/

Answer (score 2):

Adding a copy CNAME script to my `package.json` scripts worked for me as it wasn't being published to `gh-pages` branch automatically in the React Create App build dir.

```
"copy": "cp ./CNAME ./build/CNAME",
"predeploy": "yarn build && yarn copy",
```